# Can I cancel dd command and rebuild partition table?

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, live-cd, mbr, dd

I am attempting to fix the partition table on a 1 TB hard drive. GParted on my live disk sees the drive as being "2 TiB"... It is clearly labelled as 1 TB on the outside.

I started a low level reformat using `dd` but it is progressing at about 290 Kbps. It is going to take approximately 55 days to format this drive at that rate. Not exactly acceptable. Can I abort this and try some other method?

The drive is connected via USB 2.0 and `dd` is running off of a live disk. Can I abort the operation without harming the hard drive? There is no data on the drive, I want to make it usable.

Comment: Also, the fact that `dd` is because you didn't specify a block size. Add `bs=1M` (or 10M) should speed things up quite a bit and reduce the time taken to something more reasonable like a few hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can abort `dd`.

Just go to the terminal where `dd` is running and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Aborting `dd` will not *roll things back* to the way they were before `dd` started writing a stream of data to the disk. But that's fine, because you don't need that.

If your goal is just to clear out all the partitions on the disk and make a new partition table, you can do this in any partitioning utility. It's fast, because it doesn't write over most of the disk. Data might still be recoverable, but old files won't pop up out of nowhere or anything of the sort.

(And if you *do* need to securely erase the disk, `dd` might *not* be adequate for that.)

Writing a new partition table to the disk is traditionally what people mean when they say "low level format." Actually there's something else called that too, which is typically not possible through software, and which *also* doesn't involve writing data all over the disk. (Modern hard disks contain some data structures used internally by the drive firmware.) `dd` will not write in those "low level" areas.

---

As for the problem that motivated you to run `dd` on the drive in the first place, if creating a new partition table in GParted or other utilities doesn't fix it and make the disk's size appear correctly, I suspect `dd` wouldn't improve on that situation either.

There might be something (physically) wrong with the drive, but I wonder if maybe you've come up against some strange bug in GParted (or the version of GParted you're using) instead. Do things work any differently with [`fdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/fdisk.8.html)? (`fdisk` is not nearly as powerful as [`parted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/parted.8.html) or [`gparted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/gparted.8.html), but you don't need to move or resize any partitions, so it should be adequate to the task.)

If you haven't done so, I also recommend checking the drive for failure indicators and defects. Assuming it supports [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) (most drives these days do), you can use [`smartctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/smartctl.8.html) (see also [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)). You can scan the drive for surface defects with [`badblocks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/badblocks.8.html), though given how long `dd` was taking to run, that might take a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried to create a new partition table with gparted and it threw an error. When I changed from the msdos partition table (to a different type) and tried to create one then gparted crashed. Sorry for lack of detail, I am not near the PC at the moment. I was hopeful that a low level reformat would fix the issue with the disk. The space currently shows as "unallocated" but displays 2tb of space when I know there is only 1tb. I believe this is why the partition table fails... Still unsure!

Comment: Hey! I am tempted to think that the drive is bad. Mac OS sees the disk as "2.2 TB Media" when connected via USB and Windows wouldn't give me a file size before initializing it. I've been using Disk Utility in Mac OS X for about 24 hours trying to get the drive in Extended Mac OS Journaled (HFS+?) format. It's still says there is a day left... Drive is under warranty so back it goes I think!

Comment: Thought this might be of interest; the drive was returned to Western Digital who did not even question that there was a problem. So something was up!

Comment: Tried this, it just writes `^C` in the blank space under the last commend.

Answer (score 2):

Test `gdisk`.

It is available in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04.1 Live Iso.

Open a terminal.

Execute:

```
sudo su 
gdisk /dev/sd?
```

The `gdisk` program employs a user interface similar to that of Linux's `fdisk`, but `gdisk` modifies GPT partitions. It also has the capability of transforming MBR partitions or BSD disklabels into GPT partitions. Like the original `fdisk` program, `gdisk` does not modify disk structures until you explicitly write them to disk, so if you make a mistake, you can exit from the program with the `q` option to leave your partitions unmodified.

When creating a fresh partition table, certain considerations may be in order:

- For data disks, and for boot disks used on BIOS-based computers with GRUB as the boot loader, partitions may be created in whatever order and in whatever sizes are desired.
- Boot disks for EFI-based systems require an EFI System Partition (`gdisk` internal code `0xEF00`) formatted as FAT-32.
- Some boot loaders for BIOS-based systems make use of a BIOS Boot Partition (`gdisk` internal code `0xEF02`), in which the secondary boot loader is stored, possibly without the benefit of a filesystem.
- If Windows is to boot from a GPT disk, a partition of type Microsoft Reserved (`gdisk` internal code `0x0C01`) is recommended. This partition should be about 128 MiB in size. It ordinarily follows the EFI System Partition and immediately precedes the Windows data partitions.
- Some OSes' GPT utilities create some blank space (typically 128 MiB) after each partition. The intent is to enable future disk utilities to use this space. Such free space is not required of GPT disks, but creating it may help in future disk maintenance.

Options:

```
-l List the partition table for the specified device and then exits. 

b Save partition data to a backup file.

c Change the GPT name of a partition. 

d Delete a partition.

i Show detailed partition information.

l Display a summary of partition types.

n Create a new partition.

o Clear out all partition data.

p Display basic partition summary data. 

q Quit from the program without saving your changes.

r Enter the recovery & transformation menu.

s Sort partition entries.

t Change a single partition's type code.

v Verify disk.

w Write data.

? Print the menu.
```

Comment: Thanks! I am running off of a live cd and I'm not sure how well apt-get works in that environment.

Comment: @Shrout1 `apt-get` does work on live. (You won't typically be able to install more software than fits in the live environment's RAMdisk, but that's usually only a problem when installing or upgrading *a lot* of software within the live environment.) You should be able to install and run [`gdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/gdisk.8.html) without problems, if it's not in your live system, *but it's likely already installed!* (kyodake: you may want to update your post to reflect that it may already present). I've just checked on a 14.04.1 live ISO; it has `gdisk`.

Comment: @eliah kagan Thanks again! I will give this suggestion a try if my other efforts fail :)